# Convert string with space-delimiters to array. And output this array, like a string

Tags: java, arrays, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem, that I already resolved in bash/powershell.
I need to store arguments of java in a variable.

```
SET JAVA_ARGS="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m"
java %JAVA_ARGS% -jar my.jar
```

When I am making this, i am receiving

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m -Xmx2048m
```

Very nice, I tried to resolve this in powershell

```
$JavaArgs="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m"
${JavaArgsArray}=$JavaArgs.Split(" ")
java $JavaArgsArray -jar my.jar
```

In bash, I did this

```
java_arguments="-Xms256m -Xmx2048m"
IFS=' ' read -r -a array_java_arguments <<< "${java_arguments}"
java "${array_java_arguments [@]}" -jar my.jar
```

But, I need to have version in cmd, how to resolve this ? Could You help me, please ?
I need to get from variable, the array, and I have to use this array in a script. Without delimiters, just something like convert string to array, output should be the same.
For example, if I have:

```
ECHO %JAVA_ARGS%
```

Output

```
-Xms256m -Xmx2048m
```

I have to have the same output from something like:

```
ECHO %ARRAY_JAVA_ARGS%
```

Comment: Try separating them with a different delimiter like `;` or `,`

Comment: Why are you assigning quotes to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy.
I used:

```
java "'%JAVA_ARGS%' -jar my.jar"
```

Need to do:

```
java "%JAVA_ARGS% -jar my.jar"
```

Just don't use:

```
'%JAVA_ARGS%'
```

Use:

```
%JAVA_ARGS%
```